# Implementing Karatsuba algorithm in Haskell

Tags: algorithm, haskell, multiplication

I just got to know about Karatsuba Algorithm, and I tried to implement it in Haskell.

Here is my code:

```
(***) :: Integer -> Integer -> Integer
x *** y
    | max x y < ub = x*y    
    | otherwise =z2*base*base + ((x1+x0)***(y1+y0)-z2-z0)*base + z0
        where
            base =10^((length . show $ max x y) `div` 2)
            z2 =x1***y1
            z0 = x0***y0
            (x1, x0) = helper x
            (y1, y0) = helper y
            helper n = (n `div` base, n `mod` base)
            ub = 10000
```

This works accurately as long as I checked with large numbers like 20 -30 digits and fast enough for 10-20 digits. However, this is a a lot slower than normal `*` when 100 digits or even bigger numbers. How I can improve this algorithm?

Comment: This `base =10^((length . show $ max x y) `div` 2)` is not good. Although GHC's `Show` instance for `Integer` is orders of magnitude faster than Java's `BigInteger.toString()` or Python's `str` for large numbers, that is still fairly slow (think about what it _has_ to do). You should get a nice speedup using `GHC.Float.integerLogBase` there. Still better if you used a power-of-2 base, probably.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Actually I doubt you could improve the performance to beat the naive operator - Haskell use [GMP](http://gmplib.org/) under the hood, which should automatically use Toom-3 or other algorithms when the algorithm works well for the value range. The naive Karatsuba might not be even used, but the Toom series is said to be algorithmically close to it. If you come to think about it, there's no reason for GHC to not use some advanced algorithm for multiplication since they already supported it out of the box.

The last time I checked, GMP is blazing fast and even when used in the normal double range, is at least as fast as gcc's compilation result.

There's a [proposal](http://hackage.haskell.org/trac/ghc/wiki/ReplacingGMPNotes/HaskellLibrary) on removing GMP from GHC, but it seems rather inactive.

EDIT: Thanks to @danvari, here are the different algorithms GMP uses: http://gmplib.org/manual/Multiplication-Algorithms.html#Multiplication-Algorithms. It seems Karatsuba does get used when the numbers are small enough, and aside from the usual Toom-Cook family, FFT is also used.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I see. In that case, my algorithm is not too bad, and it is just `*` is really fast?

Comment: Could be the case, at least that is my idea. I used GMP several years ago, and find it to be amazing. It seems there are a lot of algorithms there are rather cutting edge research ideas, so I wouldn't expect it to be surpassed easily.

Comment: You might get a bit of more performance out of the program, that's for sure - but to make it faster than the `*` in GHC should be very hard to do, if not impossible using Karatsuba.

Comment: I see. Well, it was a good practice to implement algorithm. Thank you for your answer.

Comment: GMP uses the following algorithms for integer multiplication (ordered by the size of the input numbers): 1. The naive (schoolbook) algorithm, 2. Karatsuba, 3. Toom 3-Way, 4. Toom 4-Way, 5. Higher degree Toom'n'Half, 6. Fast Fourier Transform multiplication.

Comment: @danvari nice, I tried to search for that information but didn't dig that up nowhere. Could you edit in a link for reference?

Comment: http://gmplib.org/manual/Multiplication-Algorithms.html#Multiplication-Algorithms